# While extracting link from search page using xpath in lxml receiving empty list but in on element page its showing there are 12 links with same xpath

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, web-crawler, lxml

While I am trying to extract link from Google search page using xpath in lxml , I am receiving an empty list but in on element page its showing there are 12 links with same xpath.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
a=requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=cupboard')
doc=html.fromstring(a.content)
res=doc.xpath('//div[@class="yuRUbf"]//h3[@class="LC20lb DKV0Md"]')
print(res)
```

Comment: If you take a look at the html you're actually parsing with `html.tostring(doc)`, you'll see the elements that you see in the browser aren't actually there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `//div[@class="yuRUbf"]//h3[@class="LC20lb DKV0Md"]`

with smth like this `//div[@class="g"]//h3`